# worldToScreen() - How does it work?

Tags: java, android, game-engine

I am reading an android tutorial for game development that explains how to convert in-game coordinates to actual pixels. Simple enough. This is done via function `worldToScreen()` as follows:

```
public Rect worldToScreen(float objectX, float objectY, float objectWidth, float objectHeight){

        int left = (int) (screenCentreX - ((currentViewportWorldCentre.x - objectX) * pixelsPerMetreX));
        int top = (int) (screenCentreY - ((currentViewportWorldCentre.y - objectY) * pixelsPerMetreY));
        int right = (int) (left + (objectWidth * pixelsPerMetreX));
        int bottom = (int) (top + (objectHeight * pixelsPerMetreY));

        convertedRect.set(left, top, right, bottom);

        return convertedRect;
    }
```

It seems to return a rectangle object containing the four points that a square object would occupy.

1. Why does it use a square?
2. Why is it substracting top/left and adding bottom/right?

A thorough explanation will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer to question 1**

He's using a rectangle probably because it's a simple geometry object that is already implemented in `Java` and in most gaming libraries, like the one you are using (i can see he's using the `Rect` class).

Rectangle is also a common solution in 2D games when you want to implement simple collision detection for example.

**Answer to question 2**

You ask why he's adding `bottom` and `right`... But i can only see that he's adding `top` and `left`.
He's doing that because the `y` axis goes from up to down, and the `x` axis goes from left to right.

So to get the `bottom` point you have to add the `y` coordinate of the top point to the `height` of the rectangle.

Same for the `right` point, you have to add the `x` coordinate of the `left` point to the `width` of the rectangle.

In the hope that my `Paint` skills can come useful i made a drawing that probably will help you understand:
[image]

To make the drawing and my answer even more clear:

top + height = bottom

left + width = right

**PS:** "he" is the guy who made the tutorial that you're following.

Comment: great answer my friend. The drawing was the actual icing on the cake of my understanding. Thanks so much!